# is there a way to change date in a column that has date and percentage to only percentage in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x

I have a column in my dataset that contains dates and percentage values. I don't need the date to be in there, I only need the percentage values. What line of code could I use to remove the date to have only the percentage values ?

I tried this code :

```
import re

# Extract percentage value from imd_band column
data5['imd_band'] = data5['imd_band'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', str(x))[0] if re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', str(x)) else None)
```

And the date disappeared but I only have my values and the values are no longer in percentage range. Initially I had something like 90-100% after running the code I now have only 90.

Comment: Does every row have the date in that column? Is the date always before the percentage range? Does the date always have the same number of characters? Some sample data would really help here.

Comment: NOT EVERY ROW
THE DATE ALWAYS COME AFTER THE PERCENTAGE